# MongoDB $lookup is persisting combined document in database

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I've 2 separate collections and I am trying to fetch joined result from MongoDB using C# driver.

```
public class ModuleEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public User? User { get; private set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
}

// BsonClassMap
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ModuleEntity>(map =>
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.MapIdMember(x => x.Id);
});
```

I am trying with following Aggregate pipeline

```
var moduleEntity = await _moduleEntities.Aggregate()
            .Match(x => x.Id == id)
            .Lookup<ModuleEntity, User, ModuleEntity>(_users, x => x.UserId, x => x.Id, x => x.User)
            .Unwind(x => x.User, new AggregateUnwindOptions<User> { PreserveNullAndEmptyArrays = true })
            .As<ModuleEntity>()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But for some reason this fetch query is updating actual `ModuleEntity` collection in db and after this query `ModuleEntity` collection has following type of json which is weird because I couldn't find anything related to persisting result or am I using pipeline wrong?

```json
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"R88NX3XQrUObchorbQUBRA=="),
    "UserId": 123,
    "User": {
        "_id": 123,
        "firstName": "john"
    }
}
```

At `ModuleEntity` saving time json looks something like this:

```json
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"R88NX3XQrUObchorbQUBRA=="),
    "UserId": 123,
    "User": null
}
```

If I add `UnmapMember` for `User` in `ModuleEntity` collection then upper query throws

```
MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException: Expression not supported: x.User.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Translators.ExpressionToFilterTranslators.ToFilterFieldTranslators.MemberExpressionToFilterFieldTranslator.Translate(TranslationContext context, MemberExpression memberExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Translators.ExpressionToFilterTranslators.ToFilterFieldTranslators.ExpressionToFilterFieldTranslator.Translate(TranslationContext context, Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.LinqProviderAdapterV3.TranslateExpressionToField[TDocument](LambdaExpression expression, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
```

Ideally, fetch query shouldn't persist result in actual collection.